# rules task written on mvel not building and throwing java compilation error

Tags: jbpm, business-rules

I have this rules task written on mvel dialect, the globalorder variable is defined on my business process and specified on the TaskData I/O section.

For the onEntry section I wrote, on MVEL dialect:

package com.myspace.ordersdemo;

import java.lang.Number;
import com.myspace.ordersdemo.Order globalorder

rule "DiscountApplying"
dialect "mvel"
when
Order( )
( Order( amount > 200 ) )
then globalorder.DiscountApplying = true
end

When I try to deploy on my local business-central, I get this strange error, can somebody give me any clues on this?

"ERROR","[KBase: defaultKieBase]: Unable to Analyse Expression package com.myspace.ordersdemo;import java.lang.Number;import com.myspace.ordersdemo.Order
globalorder;rule ""DiscountApplying"";  dialect ""mvel"";   when;       Order( );       ( Order( amount > 200 ) );  then globalorder.DiscountApplying = true;end:[Error: class not found:
package com.myspace.ordersdemo;import java.lang.Number;import com.myspace.ordersdemo.Order globalorder;rule ""DiscountApplying"";
dialect ""mvel"";   when;       Order( );       ( Order( amount > 200 ) );  then globalorder.DiscountApplying = true;end][Near : {... import com.myspace.ordersdemo.Order g ....}]

Comment: Looks like you're confusing drools with MVEL. This thread might help you getting started - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473204/drools-differences-between-the-mvel-and-java-dialects

Answer (score 0):

The snippet that you have provided actually belongs to drools which will throw syntax when you run as MVEL expression inside OnEntry Script, either define this inside a separate drl file, add an agenda and call it from a separate rule task or fix your on entry script to use MVEL syntax. For example, a valid syntax in your case would be:

```
If(globalorder.amount > 200) {
    globalorder.DiscountApplying = true;
}
```

[MVEL documentation](http://mvel.documentnode.com/#if-then-else) may help you with appropriate syntax